# Transform JSfiddle to actual website - random image generator website

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Hello I want to create a random image generator website, and recently found a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alicevo12/4xs7ebao/show/) file online that suits my intention. I want to transfer that JSfiddle file to HTML with CSS and JS. When I run it in JSfiddle it works fine but when I apply it to the actual website it only recognize the HTML and CSS but not the JS, which means it looks alright but doesn't generate a random image. I'm kinda new to coding and don't know what went wrong, Please have a look at my coding below. Thanks alot.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="style.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="banner-message">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button id="button">Change image</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="img"></div>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url(../Arcane/Images/thefoollabel.png);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

ul{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}

ul li.active a{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}
.logo img{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.main{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.title h1{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #fff;
}

.subtitle{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.subtitle h1{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #bebc53;
}

.subsubtitle{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 66%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.subsubtitle h1{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #bebc53;
}

.button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.btn{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}
```

JS

```js
var images =[
    'https://i.ibb.co/37bntqy/img-2.png',
    'https://i.ibb.co/yXcJBVg/img-1.png',
    ];
    
    // Set default image for load
    document.getElementById('img').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[0] + "')";
    
    var button = document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        // handle click and change background image
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      document.getElementById('img').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[r] + "')";
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle default executes onload. You need to wrap the JS in a load handler

```
const images = [
  'https://i.ibb.co/37bntqy/img-2.png',
  'https://i.ibb.co/yXcJBVg/img-1.png',
];

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById('img').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[0] + "')";
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // handle click and change background image
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById('img').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[r] + "')";
  });
})
```

This code can go into the head or in an external JS file and the CSS in main.css

```js
const images = [
  'https://i.ibb.co/37bntqy/img-2.png',
  'https://i.ibb.co/yXcJBVg/img-1.png',
];

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  document.getElementById('imgDiv').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[0] + "')";
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // handle click and change background image
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById('imgDiv').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[r] + "')";
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url(../Arcane/Images/thefoollabel.png);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
}
#imgDiv {  min-height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id="button">Change image</button>
</div>

<div id="imgDiv">Test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much I just apply it and it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,

The code is correct but all you should do is to add the `<script>` tag that loads your `script` file at the end of your body, javascript cannot get your `img` div because dom elements didn't load yet.

```
<script src="style.js"></script>
</body>
```